# Generic form to create components

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am trying to create a generous and quick to create components in a GUI, the code that I did was the following, but I know he does not do what I want, and I also do not know how I can do.

```
#using <System.Drawing.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

public ref class GUI : public Form
{
private:
    int x, y;
    String^ text;
    Button^ btm;

public:
    GUI(int _x, int _y, String^ caption)
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        text = caption;
        init_btm();
    }
    void init_btm()
    {
        btm = gcnew Button();
        btm->Location = Point(x, y);
        btm->Text = text;
        Controls->Add(btm);
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::Run(gcnew GUI(20,20,"Ola mundo"));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create something like this...

rather, a dynamic way to create components and add components to the form
well, what I would do is create a class where I can access it, and create multiple buttons, and this class, add these buttons on Form maybe something like this:

```
ADD_BTM^ btm;
btm->Add(20,20,"Hello 1");
btm->Add(20,20,"Hello 2");
```

You also may be wondering, why I did not "design" my interface, I am studying C++/CLI, and I'm trying to create this program, just to study.
I appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you describe the issue a little more? What does it show, if anything? Is there an error?

Comment: I'm curious, why are you trying to use C++/CLI for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to add new button to the form, you just need to add parameters to the method and then call it repeatedly:

In `public` section of `GUI`:

```
void AddButton(int x, int y, String^ caption)
{
    auto button = gcnew Button();
    button->Location = Point(x, y);
    button->Text = caption;
    Controls->Add(button);
}
```

In `main`:

```
auto form = gcnew GUI();

form->AddButton(20, 20, "Hello 1");
form->AddButton(40, 40, "Hello 2");

Application::Run(form);
```

(The code uses `auto` from C++11. If you don't use VS 2010, just replace them with the actual type.)

Comment: To add one function handle in button, for example, if I clicked in button, show de messagebox.... How i can do this ?